# VUE component ignoring CSS

Tags: css, vue.js

I have the following VUE component:

```
<template>
      <div>
          <div class="bottom-footer">  
            {{msg}}
          </div>    
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'LayoutFooter',
      data () {
        return {
          msg: 'my test'
        }
      },
      mounted () {
      }
    }
    </script>

    <!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
    <style scoped>
      .bottom-footer {
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #A7BFE8;
      }
    </scoped>
```

VUE is completely ignoring my scoped CSS. When page is rendered its simply not applied. There are no console errors. Ive tried removing the scoped attribute and its still ignored. Any ideas why VUE is doing this?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: Yes, Im using the cli generated webpack template

Comment: Assuming you're running the dev task to automatically compile code?

Comment: Inspect the element and see what it's not what you expect. This code should (and likely does) work just fine. I'm better it's a CSS thing.

Comment: @ m.a.solano93 That's correct

Comment: @ Bill Criswell I inspected the element its simply not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style scoped>
.bottom-footer {
height: 200px;
background-color: #A7BFE8;
}
    </style>
```

you need to close style